# Quadratic form and Lagrange's reduction

Tags: linear-algebra, quadratic-forms

I used Lagrange's reduction to make a normal form of quadratic form. I got $y_1^2 - y_2^2 + y_3^2$, but in answers is written $y_1^2 + y_2^2 - y_3^2$. Are they equivalent?

Comment: Please tell us the definition of "normal form" and "equivalence" in this context. It looks to me that they are equivalent but it depends on the exact definitions.

Comment: It is just a convention to keep the positive diagonals first, followed by the negative ones. If your vectors are matching then its equivalent.

Comment: @StubbornAtom you can write it as answer, I'll mark it as final answer.